# How to use monotonic constraints on xgboost in scala/pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

I am using [pyspark wrapper](https://medium.com/@bogdan.cojocar/pyspark-and-xgboost-integration-tested-on-the-kaggle-titanic-dataset-4e75a568bdb) for using xgboost in pyspark.

I want to use monotonicity constraint in my model as described [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/monotonic.html#monotonic-constraints).

It is easy to do it using the python xgboost model, but I want to use it in a distributed manner.

Any Idea of​ how to use monotonicity constraints in scala or pyspark?